# CURL - Unknown form option

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to make an HTTP POST request, I have two text inputs and 3 files to be uploaded

I can't seem to get the files to upload, when I try to add the to the form using

```
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "brush", CURLFORM_FILE, brush_image, CURLFORM_END);
```

The return value of the function is `CURL_FORMADD_UNKNOWN_OPTION`, I cant figure out what am I doing wrong, here's my code

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;   
static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);  


curl_formadd(&formpost,&lastptr,CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "letter", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "Letter A",CURLFORM_END);
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "points", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "a b c", CURLFORM_END);

// these call return the unknown option
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "brush", CURLFORM_FILE, brush_image, CURLFORM_END);
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "lines", CURLFORM_FILE, lines_image, CURLFORM_END);
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "downsample", CURLFORM_FILE, downsample_image, CURLFORM_END);


curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit", CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send", CURLFORM_END);

curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        // does not go here...
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_formfree(formpost);
```

Comment: What is `brush_image` declared as, and where is it initialized? Or maybe you are using an older version of curl that does not support `CURLFORM_FILE`?

Comment: Also, you are leaking `formpost` if `curl_easy_init()` fails.

Comment: brush_image's type is std::string, it is initialized earlier, it has a value, I verified with the debugger.

Comment: changing the string to char* seems to work, any idea why?

Comment: Because `curl_formadd()` is expecting a `char*`, it has no concept of `std::string` (remember, curl is a C-based API, there is no `std::string` in C). Since `brush_image` is a `std::string`, use `brush_image.c_str()` when passing it to `curl_formadd()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `std::string` variables to `curl_formadd()`.  It has no concept of `std::string`, only `char*`.  You can use the `std::string::c_str()` method to pass `char*` values:

```
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "brush", CURLFORM_FILE, brush_image.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "lines", CURLFORM_FILE, lines_image.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "downsample", CURLFORM_FILE, downsample_image.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
```